# Is there a way to create a QImage that scrolls infintely?

Tags: c++, qt, frontend, qt5, qimage

I'm working on creating this game using QT : https://www.friv.com/z/games/killcovid19/game.html?Desktop-x-x-w-x-x-xx

When playing the game, you could see the red background scrolling infintely through the game. I was thinking of creating a QT image that does this but I'm not sure how. Is there a way for this to work using QImage? Any easier way?

Comment: Read [this](https://www.scopchanov.de/background-grid-in-qt-widgets-applications/) and you might get an idea of how to make an infinite background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach I can think about is to create an image bigger than the viewport (say, twice its hight) with a repeating pattern. Start scrolling it and when it reaches the end, start scrolling from the beginning.

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , m_background("pattern2.jpg")
    , m_timer(new QTimer(this))
    , m_offset(0)
    , m_height(m_background.height() / 2)
{
    connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this]
    {
        m_offset += 2;

        if (m_offset >= m_height)
            m_offset = 0;

        update();
    });

    resize(m_background.width(), m_height);
    m_timer->start(16);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{}

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    p.drawPixmap(0, 0, m_background, 0, m_height - m_offset, m_background.width(), m_height);
}
```

Header:

```
#pragma once

#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override;

private:
    QPixmap m_background;
    QTimer* m_timer;
    int m_offset;
    int m_height;
};
```

I used QPixmap instead of QImage because it is designed and optimized for showing images on a screen (unlike QImage which is optimized for I/O)

[image]).

Comment: Little nitpick: in modern Qt, a `QPixmap` is a wrapper around a `QImage`, so `QImage` actually has a bit less overhead (one less heap block of indirection), but it has to be in a screen-compatible format so there is no conversion overhead. Thankfully the conversion is done only once, and you can even use the `QPixmap` to give you the converted image: you do the `QImage`->`QPixmap`->`QImage` roundtrip once and you end up with an image that's very fast to blit to screen, and that wastes a cacheline or two less on access.

Comment: This seems promising. Is it possible to share your header file for more details? Much appreciated @samdavydov

Answer (score 0):

A `QImage` is like a rectangular photograph, in that it has edges, and is not infinite. But copying it is "free". Think about how you could implement a physical infinitely scrolling image (i.e. out of stuff you can hold in your hands, not out of ideas in your head), and then it should be clear how to implement it using `QImage`, I hope :)